# Select for a substring in array in DB2

Tags: sql, database, db2

I have the following Car's table in DB2:

```
 id     reference
 1      31943149-blue
 2      40213982-red
 3      93713946-blue
 ...
```

Then I need to find all entries which reference ending is inside a dynamic list of colors. How could I do that?
In fact, the dynamic list of colors should be found from another query to another table, so I guess than an UNION or INNER JOIN could be better in terms of performance.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `WHERE reference LIKE '%blue' OR reference LIKE '%red' OR ....` . Prepare the query dynamically using the application language code (eg: PHP)

Comment: But the array of colors is dynamic, I don't know exactly which ones will be

Comment: That is why I said prepare the query string **dynamically**. Eg: use `foreach ..` loop

Comment: But I could have a very large list of colors, how would be the performance with lots of LIKE OR ?

Comment: Please don't spam tags. If your question is about DB2, don't tag it `mysql`.

Comment: You can use `REGEXP_LIKE` with the regexp `red|blue|green`. You can construct this regexp dynamically from the list of colors.

Comment: Thanks you all for your answerds. Could I generate the REGEXP_LIKE or the LIKE-OR dynamically as an UNION with a select from another table?

Comment: What’s your Db2 version and what’s the sample content of your “another table”?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join the two tables, using `LIKE` in the `ON` condition.

```
SELECT car.*
FROM car
JOIN colors ON car.reference LIKE ('%-' CONCAT colors.color)
```